# Como arreglo los printlight Spring error code en mi entorno visual studio?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, vscode

Tengo un problema con mi entorno de visual studio code. estoy practicando con SpringMVC y luego de importar las librerias del mismo me sale un error comun siempre sin importar como una las librerias. Intente manual y tambien por Maven. Ambos cosas me salen unos errores de el codigo.

Pero ojo. El proyecto al compilar y probar si funciona sin problemas tanto en Maven como agregando manual. No se si puede ser mi VS que debo configurar algo pero no estoy muy claro que debo hacer.

Anexo foto del error.
[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Recurda que el vscode no es un ide, SpringBoot que es lo que estás usando y no solamente spring generalmente tiene cerca de 100 librerías incluidas. Te recomiendo pasarte al IDEA Community edition, que aunque no tiene soporte para speing tiene un excelente soporte para maven. La versión de paga que dan gratis a estudiantes si tiene soporte de primer nivel para spring, si eres estudiante deberías considerarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Ya pude revisar a profundidad y el error era un plugin que tenia en mi vscode, habia conflicto entre ambos y por ello me ocurria el problema